# How to use slideToggle on a set of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to use the jQuery slideToggle() function to minimize a set of table rows. The problem I'm encountering is that while the set of rows are minimized, the animation does not seem to be taking effect. I think it has something to do with the manner in which I'm using slideToggle, calling it on  a set of results instead of on a parent element, but am not sure.

I'm using this bit of javascript and jquery to minimize a set of rows.

```
$('td').on("click", "a.collection-minimize, a.list-minimize", function(event) {                                          
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   // Get the class of the following row
   var minimize_class = $(this).parent().parent().next().attr('class');                                                 
   // trim whitespace
   minimize_class = minimize_class.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');                                         
   // Minimize all following rows of the same class.
   $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.' + minimize_class).slideToggle();                                                 
});
```

An example set of rows:

```
<tr class="collection-original">
    <td>
        <a class="collection-minimize" onclick="return false" href="#">Minimize collection</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class=" collection-original" style="display: table-row;"></tr>                 
<tr class=" collection-original" style="display: table-row;"></tr>
<tr class=" collection-original" style="display: table-row;"></tr>
<tr class=" collection-original" style="display: table-row;"></tr>
```

A live page where this is being used can be viewed here: http://iodocs.vky.me/whitehat#Application-API-PUT-Modify-an-application.

Answer (score 0):

See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/DEPjD/

```
 minimize_class = minimize_class.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').trim();
```

Or:

```
minimize_class = minimize_class.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').replace(/ /g, '');
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. The behavior I'm looking for is when 'Minimize collection' is clicked, I would like for the sibling elements to slide into the 'Minimize collection' row; not click, wait a second, and then have those rows disappear. Hope this makes the question more clear.